# Excel VBA Run-time error Type mismatch 13

Tags: vba, excel

Unfortunately my collaegue is currently on vacation and I'm sitting here with his VBA-Code, where I always trigger the run-time 13 Error. Any Help? The Error-Code is marked with **

```
Function checkForMapping(sheetName As String, checkColumn As Integer, displayColumn As Integer, firstRow As Integer, text As String) As Boolean

Worksheets(sheetName).Activate

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim values As String
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim currentValue As String


For currentRow = firstRow To lastRow Step 1
    **If Not Round(Cells(currentRow, checkColumn), 1) = Round(1, 10) Then**
        currentValue = Cells(currentRow, displayColumn)
        If Not InStr(values, currentValue) > 0 Then
            If Len(values) > 0 Then
                values = values & ", "
            End If
            values = values & currentValue
        End If
    End If
Next

checkForMapping = (Len(values) > 0)

If checkForMapping Then
    result = MsgBox(text & " " & values, (vbOKOnly + vbInformation), "Info")
End If
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where do you get the error?  Step through with F8 and tell us which line is highlighted when the error occurs

Comment: @Dave he's put a ** on the line

Comment: That error message normally means a data type mismatch, place a breakpoint, or when the application breaks, step through it, you'll see where the error lies...

Comment: When you step through what does ?currentRow show as if you put that in the Immediate window?

Comment: @TimEdwards: currentRow = 2 ; checkColumn = 21

Comment: Thanks, that seems ok, what will ?Cells(2, 21) return? Or what's the value of U2?

Comment: No Sir, thank you! It is either 1 or #NV. In this case U2 = #NV, but U3 for example is 1 and so on.

Comment: #NV is not a numeric expression as expected by Round function, so it's normal to have an error. You need to check for numeric value before (for example with `IsNumeric(Cells(currentRow, checkColumn))` )

Comment: what's that `Round(1, 10)` for? Simply use `1`.  Also `Step 1` is not necessary since it's by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe add the following line before:

`If Not IsError(Cells(currentrow, checkcolumn)) Then`

and then remember to stick in another

`End If`
after

Comment: No worries, completely up to you and no pressure whatsoever but as you're new to SO you may wish to mark an answer if it's given you what you need. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) will explain further.

Answer (score 0):

what if using:

```
If Left(Cells(currentRow, checkColumn).Value2, 1) <> "1" Then
```